# Prevent clickthrough on Google Maps MarkerImage

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers, preventdefault, click-through

I'm using Google Maps on my page and I want to prevent clicks on any of the `MarkerImage`s I've set up from bubbling up to the parent container of the map. Is this possible? `MarkerImage`s, when rendered on the page, seem to be just a series of `div`s with inline styling and no IDs or classes - I don't think I can target them specifically in order to use `e.preventDefault();` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a stop()-method for mouse-events that should stop the propagation, but for me it doesn't work.

Another approach would be

```
map.getDiv().onclick=function(e)
{
  if(e){e.stopPropagation();}
  else if(window.event){window.event.cancelBubble=true;}  
}
```

...this should stop the propagation of clicks to outside of the map.